# ARKit - initially placing object in ARSKView at a certain heading/angle from camera

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm creating my anchor and 2d node in ARSKView like so:

```
func displayToken(distance: Float) {
        print("token dropped at: \(distance)")
        guard let sceneView = self.view as? ARSKView else {
            return
        }

        // Create anchor using the camera's current position
        if let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame {
            removeToken()

            // Create a transform with a translation of x meters in front of the camera
            var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
            translation.columns.3.z = -distance
            let transform = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)

            // Add a new anchor to the session
            let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: transform)
            sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
        }
    }

func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
        // Create and configure a node for the anchor added to the view's session.
        if let image = tokenImage {
            let texture = SKTexture(image: image)
            let tokenImageNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
            tokenImageNode.name = "token"
            return tokenImageNode
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

This places it exactly in front of the camera at a given distance (z). What I want to also do is take a latitude/longitude for an object, calculate an angle or heading in degrees, and initially drop the anchor/node at this angle from the camera. I'm currently getting the heading by using the GMSGeometryHeading method, which takes users current location, and the target location to determine the heading. So when dropping the anchor, I want to put it in the right direction towards the target location's lat/lon.  How can I achieve this with SpriteKit/ARKit?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question a bit please?

Perhaps the following lines can help you as example. There the cameraNode moves using a basic geometry-formula, moving obliquely depending on the angle (in Euler) in both x and y coordinates

```
var angleEuler = 0.1
let rotateX = Double(cameraNode.presentation.position.x) - sin(degrees(radians: Double(angleEuler)))*10
let rotateZ = Double(cameraNode.presentation.position.z) - abs(cos(degrees(radians: Double(angleEuler))))*10
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x:Float(rotateX), y:0, z:Float(rotateX))
```

If you want an object fall in front of the camera, and the length of the fall depend on a degree just calculate the value of "a" in the geometry-formula "Tan A = a/b" and update the node's "presentation.position.y"

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I clarified my question a bit to understand what I'm trying to accomplish.